# NDSolve::conarg : The arguments should be ordered consistently

Tags: differential-equations

Here is the code I was written. I want to have a surface plot. But when I write this it shows "The arguments should be ordered consistently "

```
a = 0.7;    
    b = 0.7;    
    d = 1.0;    
    phi = 0.01;    
    M = 3.0;    
    h1 = 1 + a*Cos[2.0*3.14*x];    
    h2 = -d - b*Cos[2.0*3.14*x + phi];          
    sol1 = NDSolve[{D[D[D[D[s[x, y], y], y], y], y] == 
        M^2*D[D[s[x, y], y], y], s[x, h1] == q/2, 
       s[x, h2] == -q/2, (D[s[x, y], y] /. y -> h1) == 
        0, (D[s[x, y], y] /. y -> h2) == 0}, s, {x, -1, 1}, {y, h2, h1}]
```

Comment: The error comes from terms like this: `s[x, 1 + 0.7 Cos[6.28 x]]` (i.e., `s[x, h1]`.  I think the only way to have boundary conditions along a curve like this is to use [FEM](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html).  Then you can set up your domain as an `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: Thanks. But I have seen such kinds of problems in many research paper tackled using NDSOLVE.

Comment: If you follow the link to the FEM documentation, you'll find I was recommending `NDSolve`.  FEM is one of its methods.

Comment: Okay. Actually I am new in Mathematica. Trying to learn it.

Comment: Actually, it's not a good recommendation.  FEM doesn't seem to handle order 4 PDEs, at least at this point.

Comment: Then what should I try?

Comment: I think the approach in [your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148081/trying-to-make-a-conturplot-using-parametric-ndsolve) is a more promising approach, since you don't really have a PDE (no x derivatives).  The problem there is finding good starting initial conditions for [the shooting method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html).  But probably no one will bother to try things out **unless you post the code** for that question.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to write the code according to your suggestions and will post it along with a new questions in upcoming days. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the way you defined your dependent variable `s[x,y]`. Infact `s` depends on `y` directly and on `x` indirectly through the boundary conditions, which can be treated as a parameter. So you are suppose to solve an ode for `s[y]` not a pde.

```
a = 0.7; b = 0.7; d = 1.0; phi = 0.01; M = 3.0; q = 0.5; x = 1;

h1 = 1 + a*Cos[2.0*3.14*x];

h2 = -d - b*Cos[2.0*3.14*x + phi];

sol = NDSolve[{D[D[D[D[s[y], y], y], y], y] == M^2*D[D[s[y], y], y], 
      s[h1] == q/2, s[h2] == -q/2, (D[s[y], y] /. y -> h1) == 0, 
     (D[s[y], y] /. y -> h2) == 0}, s, {y, h2, h1}]

Plot[s[y] /. sol, {y, h2, h1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I need a conturplot of s. Not for a particular value of x what you have done.